# is there any way to get all application installed in user's iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sandbox

I know a little bit about sandbox. However, can I get a list of total applications installed in user's iPhone.I want this to be done with the all iPhone device whether they are jailbroken or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got a list of all installed application in my iPhone. It uses private framework but it's not jail broken device.

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];

    SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
    NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
```

I have tried this code and it's workings well on iOS9.

Comment: absolutely great! thanks a lot buddy!! upvoted!

Comment: can i get the icons of all installed apps?

Comment: I have googled it a lot but not able to fetch the icons using bundle identifier, I need it urgently. Any help will be appreciated.